# How to not have freestyle lines affected by exposure

Tags: eevee-render-engine, freestyle, color-management

I was working with freestyle for my first time while using the "Real Sky" addon from the blender market. I am working in eevee. If you are familiar with Real Sky, you know it is common place to adjust the exposure in the color management section. Unfortunately, adjusting the exposure also adjusts the freestyle line color. I would like to know how to keep the colors I have picked regardless of the scene's lighting. You can see what I mean in the attached picture. I know I can duplicate each object and have them on a separate view layer with freestyle and transparent material and have different exposures for each view layer in compositing. This seems like a bulky fix considering if I make a small adjustment, I need to make sure to adjust it in both view layers. How do I keep the line color intact while adjusting the exposure for the non-line-art rendering?
[image]